# How can you tell if an ELF Binary was Built with BINDNOW?

Tags: c, gcc

Is there an easy way to tell if an ELF binary was built with lazy binding disabled (-Wl,-z,now)?

Answer (score 4):

Found it, running this command tells you if BIND_NOW is used:

```
readelf -a /bin/login | grep BIND
```

> 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW